# pass array in the "data" tag at server side - bootstrap ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to figure out if i can send a array in the data tag:
My client JS code looks like :

```
                     $.ajax({
        url: '/mobiledoc/jsp/aco/Beneficiary/ptmmview.jsp',
        data: {
            "action":"savePatientRecords",
            "ptId":strPtId,
            "PatientVal":PatientVal,
            "Qid":Qid,
            "QType":QType
                            "Array" : ??
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (responseMsg) {
        // gets the response message back from server
            loadMilestoneData();
            alert(responseMsg);
```

Comment: Just to reiterate I wish to send a array. I know while receiving i can just change the dataType : 'json'. But thats not my concern.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes you can. First use **method** instead of **type** post. Like this...

```
method: 'post'
```

JQuery should serialise the data for you.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mobiledoc/jsp/aco/Beneficiary/ptmmview.jsp',
    data: {
        "action": "savePatientRecords",
            "ptId": strPtId,
            "PatientVal": PatientVal,
            "Qid": Qid,
            "QType": QType,
            "Array": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    method: 'post',
    success: function (responseMsg) {
        // gets the response message back from server
        loadMilestoneData();
        alert(responseMsg);
    }
});
```

If not, then use **JSON.stringify** to turn your objects/arrays into a string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mobiledoc/jsp/aco/Beneficiary/ptmmview.jsp',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "action": "savePatientRecords",
            "ptId": strPtId,
            "PatientVal": PatientVal,
            "Qid": Qid,
            "QType": QType,
            "Array": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    }),
    dataType: 'text',
    method: 'post',
    success: function (responseMsg) {
        // gets the response message back from server
        loadMilestoneData();
        alert(responseMsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes : JSON.stringify({ paramName: array}) WORKS!! i can actually pass json array to other side :)

Answer (score 0):

Servers typically don't read arrays like that. To be cautious, flatten the array on the client first:

```
data: {
        ...
        "Array" : theArray.join(',')  // beware of values with ',' in them
      }
```

On the server, split the array by ','.